# How do amateur astronomers do stellar spectroscopy?

Tags: observational-astronomy, star, spectroscopy, spectra

This question consists of 2 parts:

1. How can amateur astronomers measure the spectrum of stars?
2. In addition to diffraction gratings, what equipment do they use (like telescopes, and the focal length and aperture of the telescope)?

Comment: @ScienceAJ why don't you do the following to narrow this down and add more focus 1) explain that you have a goal of getting a spectrum from a very dim object but want to start by measuring something bright and easier first, 2) mention if you have a telescope at the moment or not, or if you plan on using a camera. 3) mention a little bit about how accurately you want to measure the spectrum, and if you need to resolve individual spectral lines or not. Then you could ask about the minimum amateur setup that might be able to do it.

Comment: It might help you focus your questions to go here: https://www.rspec-astro.com/sample-projects/ and look at spectroscopy examples that some amateurs are doing with telescopes. If you only have a camera and appropriate diffraction grating, then only a few bright objects are suitable. I have no financial connection with the stuff at the link, but I did buy a grating, camera adaptor and the software.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @EdV. It pretty much solves all my questions

Comment: @ProfRob WISE is an telescope, by WISE system I mean the sub brown dwarfs and brown dwarfs discovered by WISE

Comment: You are at the early stages of a possibly life-long love affair with astronomy and I envy that: I am just a retired chemistry professor who did various spectroscopy research projects (lots of blowing stuff up with lasers). So no need for you to rush. Just start simple: what hardware, software and astronomy knowledge do you have and what project would be a good match for an enthusiastic person with that capability? Perseverance really counts, as does curiosity and skepticism. Best of success!

Comment: @ScienceAJ if the 16.5 is the magnitude of your object, you will not get lucky unless you have a decent amateur telescope at hand. That is even more true when you want to do spectroscopy. With the 50cm telescope here we can just barely see pluto at 16mag in the best of nights- without any grating. Getting started with spectroscopy I recommend doing spectra of our planets maybe first or of bright stars, and then see what you can identify, comparing it to their known spectra

Comment: Thanks a lot, @EdV

Comment: @planetmaker I shall have an telescope after a few months, but what is the focal length, aperature size, magnification in order to observe such an object?

Comment: Suggestion for a sweet amateur spectroscopy project: create a thin slit, place it parallel to and over the equator of Jupiter, and do spectroscopy there. Use the results to obtain the rotational velocity of Jupiter from the space-resolved spectrum.

Comment: @planetmaker I did that a quadrillion years ago, with a photographic plate, and read it with a Mann measuring machine a bit [like this](https://youtu.be/f3ubb7n0zOc). I was really excited by the result! Have you tried it? If so, I think that example would make for an excellent "how to get started in amateur astronomical spectroscopy" answer!

Comment: Thanks, @planetmaker. I will implement that technique

Comment: Thanks, @uhoh. I've never tried Spectroscopy before

Comment: Thanks a lot, @planetmaker. Would I need a telescope in order to do Spectroscopy with Jupiter?

Comment: @uhoh no, I didn't yet. But I recently came across that idea in some article (forgot where) and put it on my list of "possibly cool project" - especially in relation to doing this with children, youths or students. :)  @ ScienceAJ: I recon without a telescope such spatially-resolved spectroscopy will fail... you need to measure the velocity at different parts of the equator to get results. Good luck without a telescope.

Comment: I admire your ambition and enthusiasm, but it is time for a reality check: you currently have too little knowledge of spectroscopy, diffraction gratings, telescopes, etc. You would be very well served to just pick a simple beginner project. The link I provided previously shows example projects. And that plastic diffraction grating you mentioned, which I happen to have, is just a toy: good in a lecture hall for students to see spectral lines in gas discharge lamps. Don’t be discouraged, just be realistic: you need to walk before you can run.

Comment: Thank you so much, @EdV about the valuable inputs. Can you please guide me or provide pointers so that I can get a better understanding and hold on the subject?

Comment: I think you need to find a local mentor to help you learn the basics and focus on doing something feasible. Otherwise, you may end up frustrated and spinning your wheels. I cannot provide any better advice than to find a local mentor and I will post no more comments here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ad 1) There are multiple options:

- A diffraction grating in transmission like the StarAnalyzer 100 or 200, that are conveniently framed in a 1.25“ ring, so it can be attached to a standard ocular.
- A grating in reflection in the [Star‘Ex](http://www.astrosurf.com/solex/sol-ex-stars-en.html) an extension of the [Sol‘Ex](http://www.astrosurf.com/solex/sol-ex-presentation-en.html) heliospectrograph.
- there are a couple of spectrometers commercially available, including Echelle spectometers and even with optical fibres.

Ad 2)
You use what you have available, from refractors with 70/420 as I do up to Schmidt-Cassegrains like the C11 or C14 from Celestron.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot. Moreover what is C11 and C14? Also how can transmission spectroscopy be done on stars?

Comment: Watch this video by Tom Field: https://youtu.be/6MrFuNGLsUE. He tells and shows you **exactly** how to use the StarAnalyzers to do transmission spectroscopy on stars. There are lots of videos there: have a look at some.

Comment: C11/C14 = Celestron Schmidt-Cassegrains with 11“ or 14“ aperture.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. Moreover in order to make precise measurements, how do they avoid telluric contaminations?

Comment: @EdV Thanks a lot!

Comment: If Tom Field does not explain how to get rid of telluric contaminations, I won‘t do that either. (Means: I have no clue ;-)  Theoretically, you can download space-based spectra or prepare extinction spectra yourself. I have not come across infos on that from amateurs on the web.

Comment: @ScienceAJ      I know absolutely nothing about correcting telluric lines, sorry to boast, but other people do, e.g., https://www.eso.org/sci/software/pipelines/skytools/ and links therein. It is a separate question anyway.

Comment: Thanks, @EdV. No issues